# Why does the iteration not work here in cuda?

Tags: cudalink

I tried to implement Jacobi method for 1D Poisson's equation using CUDALink.

The kernel is (I use only 1 block):

```
__global__ void jacobi(float *out, float *in, mint n)
{
    __shared__ float smem[BLOCK_DIM];
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if(idx < n)
        smem[threadIdx.x] = in[idx];
    else
        smem[threadIdx.x] = in[n - 1];

    __syncthreads();

    if(threadIdx.x < BLOCK_DIM - 1 && threadIdx.x > 0)
    {
        //the iteration is here*************
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            smem[threadIdx.x] = (smem[threadIdx.x - 1] + smem[threadIdx.x + 1])/2 + 0.001;
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();
    if(idx < n)
        out[idx] = smem[threadIdx.x];

    return;
}
```

Ideal:

Since `smem[]` is shared between threads and which run in parallel, later iterations will use `smem[]` values generated by earlier iterations. Thus, although iterations between threads are not ordered perfectly, `smem[]` will converge to the solution more or less.

Real:

It seems that the threads have their own caches, so once they fetch their `smem[threadIdx.x - 1]`s and `smem[threadIdx.x + 1]`s, they will not do it again any longer(, but the essence is that `smem[]` values are changing!).

---

Later, I found a costly solution to the problem. Threads were synchronized after each iteration:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    smem[threadIdx.x] = (smem[threadIdx.x - 1] + smem[threadIdx.x + 1])/2 + 0.001;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

But the synchronizations made the iterations runs at only ~2MHz on my 1GHz GPU.

---

Are there any other solutions?